# How to optimize average rating calculation in a review system?

Tags: optimization, message-queue, async, review

I'm thinking of a designing a review system (restaurant, hotel etc) where users can drop star  reviews. Typically in a such a application, you can see the average rating of an entity along with all the individual reviews of the users.

Now, the average needs to be calculated. The approach would be to get all reviews, average the star ratings and then store it in a single field, something like `average_rating`.

But assuming it's a large-scale application, updating the average each time would not be a good idea, because it would be a significant DB load to fetch all reviews and make average of them each time (Is my thinking right here?). The average update doesn't need to be reflected instantly, so I am thinking of doing it async using task queue like Redis or similar.

If I use a task queue, what would be scenario to fire an average update? Yes, for each review, I can definitely fire an update. But let's say within 5 mins I get 1K reviews, doesn't necessarily mean I should enqueue 1K tasks.

I'm thinking of delaying the updates, something like debounce. But I'm not sure if that can be done with Celery/Kue alone. They let you add tasks, but do they let you know if a certain task (a entity update to be specific) is already enqueued? I can make another DB table to keep track of worker records, but is there any simpler approach? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 11):

> But assuming it's a large-scale application, updating the average each time would not be a good idea, because it would be a significant DB load to fetch all reviews and make average of them each time (Is my thinking right here?)

No, it is not. You are hypothesizing about an imaginary performance issue which you did not measure - that's the perfect road to unneeded overengineering. Moreover, it seems you have no real numbers at hand, which - in case it is true - makes any estimation quite absurd.

Even in a "large-scale" application, calculating the average for an item which was rated 999 times before - using a naive approach - will only require to query the values of those 1000 ratings. Any sane database system will do this in a blink of an eye (definitely quicker than the user who casts the star rating). If you have a lot of users rating simultanously, you may already have a larger DB system working in the background, or a distributed system, long before the average calculation shows up to become an issue.

But lets assume for a moment you built the whole system this way and the unlikely case will happen that you have really so many users casting ratings so quickly that this particular use case turns out to become a bottleneck. Then my preferred solution would be not to solve this with the heavy cannon of an aynchronous task queue. The first thing I would try is to make the average calculation **incrementally**: store the sum of all ratings together with their number inside the item's record. Then the new average can be calculated by simply updating these two numbers and dividing them, which is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Makes sense. It is in fact hypothetical because I am not going to implementation. Before asking a followup question, please note, I'm pushing this only for learning purpose. I thought of the idea of storing the sum. In a very rare edge case, is there any possiblity of running into race-condition several users are updating the same field at the same time. I guess I have to implement nested transaction if I want to avoid that, right?

Comment: @SadmanMuhibSamyo as mentioned in the answer, any sane DB system (or at least one that's correctly implemented and set) should be able to handle concurrent transactions over the same field without you having to develop anything special